# Wrap text inside TextView

Tags: android, xml, listview

This is my row layout.
How to get text inside listview in two lines?

row_data:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="Date"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Subject"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/subject"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:text="Status"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

I am inflating this row_data inside a ListView. Now I am facing problem in wrapping of Text inside my textView. My texts are overlapping each other.

This is the result I am getting:

[image]

I want wrapping my text to 2nd Line.. How can I achieve that?

Comment: use `Linear Layout` with orientation `horizontal` and use `layout_width` property in your `TextView`

Comment: Show mw your row data xml file.

Comment: already posted Rishabh

Comment: Ok,I added one solution please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LinearLayout` & `layout_weight` to divide all views equally here is your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="Subject"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLines="100"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead RelativeLayout use LinearLayout with equals weights.

Answer (score 0):

if you will put like these `TextView` with out using layouts so you will get error so try like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ivnotification_layout"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Date"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:ellipsize="none"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false"

                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Subject"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/subject"
                        android:ellipsize="none"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Status"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:ellipsize="none"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                        android:maxLines="100"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/status"
                         />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="Date"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="Subject"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="Status"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use this.